# Find and replace for loop shell

Tags: shell, file-handling, find-replace

Using the below command my script excutes succesfully.

```
for file in collectorlist*  ; do mv "$file" "${/bak_/{file}}" ; done
```

Now i want to move the bak_{file} to {file} to which is resetting to the original file name. i tried the below way , throws an error., your suggestion is appreciated.

```
for file in bak_collectorlist*; do mv "$file" "${/bak_/{file}}" ; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
for file in bak_collectorlist*; do mv "$file" "${file/bak_/}" ; done
```

From *bash* **man**:

> `${parameter/pattern/string`} **Pattern substitution**
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in  pathname 
>   expansion.   **Parameter  is expanded** and the **longest match of pattern**
>   against **its value is replaced with string**.  If pattern begins with /,
>   all matches of pattern are replaced with string. Normally only the
>   first match is replaced.  If pattern begins with  #, it  must  match
>   at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter.  If pattern
>   begins with %, it must match at the end of the expanded value of
>   parameter.  If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the
>   / following  pattern  may be omitted.  If parameter is @ or *, the
>   substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in
>   turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If parameter is an
>   array variable subscripted with @ or *, the  substitution operation is
>   applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list

.

**Demo**

```
$ ll bak_collectorlist*
-rw-r----- 1 klashxx klashxx 2 Jun 19 09:13 bak_collectorlist
-rw-r----- 1 klashxx klashxx 2 Jun 19 09:13 bak_collectorlist2
$
$ for file in bak_collectorlist*;do echo "$file" "${file/bak_/}" ; done
bak_collectorlist collectorlist
bak_collectorlist2 collectorlist
```

Comment: Hey @klashxx its working perfect.Can you explain how it works.,it would be helpful to understand better

Comment: @Satte See the `man` qoute  I have attached for your reference and let me know if  you need any further information

Comment: Its Perfect Thank you @ klashxx

Answer (score -1):

you need to reverse the file names in 2nd run from bak to original

```
 for file in bak_collectorlist*; do mv "./bak_/${file}" "$file"  ; done
```

Comment: i tried it gives error "${/bak_/{file}}: bad substitution"

Comment: Sorry @pritesh this wont work, since shell will think and look in another folder.